# Show that $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ is a metric , where $f$ is injective and $ f : R \to R$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have done this part but I'm not too sure about it. However the followup to this is how does the $U(3,\epsilon)$ ball is for the particular function for $\epsilon = 1,2,3$

$f(x)= 2x+1$ for $x \leq 1$ and $x+2$ for $x > 1$.

I'm not clear about the how this is linked to the first part.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write it all explicitly: $$\begin{align} U(3,\epsilon) &= \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid d(x,3) < \epsilon  \} \\ &= \{ x \in ]-\infty,1] \mid d(x,3)<\epsilon   \} \cup \{x \in \left] 1,\infty\right[ \mid d(x,3)<\epsilon \} \\ &= \{ x \in \left]-\infty,1\right] \mid 2x+1 - 7 < \epsilon \} \cup \{ x \in \left]1,+\infty\right[ \mid x+2 - 5 < \epsilon  \}\end{align}$$

Now solve each inequality (this is supposed to be easy now), paying attention to where they're supposed to hold.